# Is there a way to clone an already rendered React component including its local state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html2canvas

I need to export some part of a page as an image.
The image size should be other than the size of the component on the page. Even image ratio can be other in some cases.
To reach this ability I've found 2 libraries working better or less:

- html2canvas
- html-to-image

But I've found an issue with react components that have an internal state.
In all ways I've tried to copy them (React.cloneElement(), lodash.cloneDeep(), render of same components) I've received an initial internal state.

Here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/save-chart-as-image-8trkv

Is there any way to copy the existing react component with its local state, or is there another way to render the same component twice?

Comment: You have XY problem. If it's your own component, you need to lift up the state to parent component. Component state isn't always determined by 'this.state'. So the answer is no.

Comment: @EstusFlask unfortunately I can't lift up the state. The example in question is simplified. I have a complex page with several widgets in my project. Widgets list and configuration are not static and can be changed by a user, that's why widgets have internal states.
Maybe you know where I can read more about how react works with components state?

Comment: Widgets can have their own state but they need to sync it to a parent or global state to allow cloning. You can use extended classes with augmented `setState` (don't remember if it's allowed to replace the method), or use custom hook instead of `use...`, etc for functional components. This doesn't take nested comps into account. I can't recommend a specific reading. Proceed from worst case scenario, which is FC. You can't access a state created by `useState` from outside the function, it's local variable, at this point this is how JS works and not React.